# Displaying async data in angular 7

Tags: angular

I am getting an object from server which in one field contains a html markup. So to make angular display it a used this piece of code.

```
<p class="desc" [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(o.description)"></p>
```

With local data works perfectly. Although, with data from server, i used for the other fields the **?** parameter like this `{{o?.category}}`. 
But with the description field,i got this error,

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined

So, what's the alternative for **?** inside the byPassSecurityTrustHtml?

Comment: You could add ngIf="o"

Comment: Code is incomplete. Please show relevant html, TS file

Comment: I tried ngIf but it's not working.@bambam

Comment: I think that my problem very clear. There's no need for more details.

Comment: `<p class="desc" *ngIf="o" [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(o.description)"></p>`. 
if it somehow does not work, try with: `<ng-container *ngIf="o"><p class="desc" [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(o.description)"></p></ng-container>`

Comment: @briosheje not working either.

Comment: Is it showing the same error? If the ngIf is evaluated, then `o` must be defined, hence the error will probably look different. Is it throwing **the same error**?

Comment: yup it's showing the same error.

Comment: Then the error is likely somewhere else. Is there any other place you're using `.description`? Either in the html template, either in the typescript code.

Comment: I am sure that there the error. Because it was the case for the other fields before adding ?.

Comment: That's not the error if the above analysis is truthy. There is nothing else I can do to help you any further. The best I can do is suggest you to do the following: 1) Try removing that html code block specifically and try running your code. If the error still appears, the issue is somewhere else. 2) Check the compiled code, perhaps the compiler is somehow caching the view. 3) Search for any `.description` you're using and add a console log before and after it to see whether it's causing the undesired crash in your typescript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the elvis operator in your example, this:

```
<p class="desc" [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(o.description)"></p>
```

Should be:

```
<p class="desc" [innerHTML]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(o?.description)"></p>
```

Comment: I tried it before posting my question. Not working.
I think that we cannot pass elvis operator in an argument.

Comment: @DhiaEddine You can. I do it all the time. When adding the operator what error do you get? Technically you shouldn't get an error at all if you do that. Which means if the content isn't showing up then the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, you can pass elvis operator in any argument of any angular template. The answer is correct from a syntax point of view, it's just that, as mentioned above and in all comments, the issue is **somewhere else**.

Comment: Well; thank you guys. I will dig more in the code, to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @DhiaEddine I suggest you to take a further look at your typescript code. Just a rapid guessing from me: you're trying to access an element property **before** the server data is available.

Comment: I find o.description call outside of the subscription. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, please, I would suggest you to consider other people suggestions and actually provide more code when requested ;).

Comment: I am so sorry. I was over confident.

Comment: No problems. For further analysis, the error **couldn't** be there because `o` was defined. The only case where that error can come up is whenever `o` is undefined. In javascript (hence in typescript) if an object is defined and you try to access an invalid property, it **won't** throw an error, it will just return `undefined`. So, `o.description` can throw a type error only if `o` is undefined.